# How to make HTML page irresponsive?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a HTML page. I want to make the page irresponsive. I need that everything will sustain it's width, height, position, etc. when I minimize the browser. Can I achieve this somehow?

Comment: Dont add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` or use percentages in your CSS.

Comment: Use `position:absolute` and use fixed `px` dimensions.

Comment: set the width of your body element to an absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute values for `height, width, font-size, ...` and not relative ones.

- `height: 100px;` would be a absolute value
- `height: 20%;` would be a realtive value